# Correctly detect corners in an image opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, 3d

I have the following image from which I am detecting the corners using the following code

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
bilateral = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 9, 75, 75)
canny = cv2.Canny(bilateral, 50, 150)

corners    = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(canny,15,0.06,25)

for i in range(len(corners)):
    cv2.circle(img, (corners[i][0][0], corners[i][0][1]), 5, 255, -1)

cv2.imshow('dilated', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Not all corners are not correctly determined that is I was expecting that black corners should be determined as well as the box corners. Fortunately box corners are determined in this case but not all black corners are determined. How can I improve this result or even change my approach of getting the correct corners. Harris corners is not a good solution for this approach because I need one single point as corner but Harris corners approach return many close points as candidates for corners. Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Are focusing on detecting the box corners or the box+black corners?

Comment: Actually both.Black corners are reference corners and box corners are the main object corners.

Comment: It is not clear which corners are you focusing. Do you what to detect, the black corners or the box corners (which include 3 of the black corners). Because there are methods to find the contours of objects. Being your object, a box, it should be straightforward to find these contours and extract the corners.

Comment: Please, provide original image, so one can experiment with it.